# How to add logo (png/jpg) with title to download button on jQuery DataTable

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, jspdf

I am working on a project where I need to download PDF data from website. I used jQuery dataTable to view the data and it has functionality to download a PDF or CSV. I want to modify the PDF download button to add an image logo on the left side of title, but I have not able to do yet.

Also when we download the PDF, I want the data to take full space on the page. For example I have two columns in the dataTable, it only takes space as required, and it looks bad.

I have tried in simple HTML, CSS, JS.

My project is in .NET Core 5 MVC

The download code for the doc is working fine, but the image is not present.

```
// my table HTML
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" id="tabularDataModelHeader">
                    <!--Place to create a Dynamic header and Dynamic Select box-->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="tabularDataDiv">
                    <!--Place to create a Dynamic DataTable-->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="closeModel()">Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

creating table

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.id = 'tabular_data';
        table.classList.add('table', 'table-bordered', 'table-striped');
        table.style.width = '100%';

        // Create the table header
        var thead = document.createElement('thead');
        var headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
        var nameHeader = document.createElement('th');
        nameHeader.textContent = 'Name';
        var proposalsHeader = document.createElement('th');
        proposalsHeader.textContent = 'Proposals';

        // Append the header cells to the header row
        headerRow.appendChild(nameHeader);
        headerRow.appendChild(proposalsHeader);

        // Append the header row to the table header
        thead.appendChild(headerRow);

        // Append the table header to the table
        table.appendChild(thead);

        // Create the table body
        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

        // Append the table body to the table
        table.appendChild(tbody);

        // Append the table to the 'mydiv' div
        var mydiv = document.getElementById('tabularDataDiv');
        mydiv.appendChild(table);
```

Populating Data in dataTable

```
        $('#tabular_data').DataTable(
            {
                destroy: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        title: printFileName,
                        text: 'Export to Excel'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        title: printFileName,
                        text: 'Export to PDF',
                        customize: async function (doc) { // Make the function asynchronous
                            try {
                                var imgData = await getBase64Image('../images/avatar/PLIC.PNG'); // Use await to retrieve the image data asynchronously
                                doc.content.unshift({
                                    image: imgData,
                                    width: 100,
                                    alignment: 'left'
                                });
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                ],
                "info": true,
                "data": dataSet,
                "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, -1], [50, 100, "All"]],
                "scrollY": "calc(60vh - 120px)", // Adjust the height of the DataTable area
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": [1], // Index of the column (zero-based) you want to format
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            // Format the value with commas
                            //return data.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                            return data.toLocaleString("en-US");

                        }
                    }
                ],
                "initComplete": function () {
                    var api = this.api();

                    // Calculate the sum of values in the "Proposals" column
                    var total = api.column(1).data().reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return a + parseFloat(b);
                    }, 0);

                    // Create the footer row
                    var tfoot = document.createElement('tfoot');
                    var footerRow = document.createElement('tr');
                    var nameFooter = document.createElement('th');
                    var proposalsFooter = document.createElement('th');

                    // Set the content for the footer cells
                    nameFooter.textContent = 'Total';
                    proposalsFooter.textContent = total.toLocaleString("en-US");

                    // Append the footer cells to the footer row
                    footerRow.appendChild(nameFooter);
                    footerRow.appendChild(proposalsFooter);

                    // Append the footer row to the footer section
                    tfoot.appendChild(footerRow);

                    // Append the footer section to the table
                    $(api.table().node()).append(tfoot);
                }
            });
```